# Add Model Records when Application Starts

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a large JSON file which I want to process into different types of model records on application start up. I load the records via a AJAX call using jQuery.

I assume I want to use 'ready' event handler on Application. I am unsure how to gain a reference to the store at this early point in the application. The code below will fail to get the store.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        console.log('ready going');
        var store = this.Store(); // DOESN'T WORK
        Ember.$.getJSON('js/static/bigguy.json').then(function(bg) {
                ...process data...
        });
    }
});
```

I have made the above work if I put the processing code in a router and load it via a promise. I tried creating my own ApplicationRoute thinking maybe that would trigger immediately on app load, but not sure if URLs targeting other hash paths '#/something' would trigger that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that doing this in the ApplicationRoute.model would be the best way. What you can gain is the app will be in the loading state while you start up, which is what I wanted. Only once the promises return for model will the app transition to the next route. This allow you to jump into any hash path on the app and ensure the data  will be loaded.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.create({
    model: function() {
        var store = this.Store();
        return Ember.$.getJSON('js/static/bigguy.json').then(function(bg) {
            ...process data...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Using ApplciationRoute to push records to store on boot: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/